# Initializing an array is not needed with string.split method

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, split, nullreferenceexception

Can someone please explain why Example 1 gives a **NullReferenceException**
while Example 2 works fine

```
   Dim teachers As String()
   Dim Paragraph as string = "one,two"
```

**Example 1**

```
teachers(0) = "Mostafa"
teachers(1) = "Lina"
```

**Example 2**

```
teachers = paragraph.Split(",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never given the size for the Array, to initialize the memory for the required array length.  So, as there's no initialization, array(0) will be null.  Where as in the second case the Assignment will automatically initializes certain memory to the array, because the [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) will always returns a array.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly `teachers` is an String array.

`Dim teachers As String()` declares your string array but doesn't specify how many items are in the array or initialise any of them (it is a Null reference at this point)

Therefore trying to allocate a string to an item in the array fails (with a `NullReferenceException`) because it is not been initialised:

```
teachers(0) = "Mostafa" 'Fails
teachers(1) = "Lina"    'Also fails
```

`String.Split` is a function that "[Returns a string array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)", so when you call it, the Null Reference is *replaced* with a reference to a string array created by the `String.Split` function, so this works:

`teachers = "Mostafa,Lina".Split(","c)`

Alternatively you can declare *and* initialise the String array with one line:

`Dim teachers As String() = {"Mostafa", "Lina"}`